# How to pass a string variable to String.raw in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, template-literals

I have a variable in which I have text written in latex format

```
let textVar ="$\frac{1}{2}$"
console.log(textVar)
"$rac{1}{2}"
console.log(String.raw`$\frac{1}{2}$`)
"$\frac{1}{2}$"
```

I lose my escape characters (`\` + the next char) when I do `console.log(textVar)` I understand the functionality of escape charaters in text and I need to add double quotes (`\\`) inorder to retain them in `textVar`, which I cannot do

I found that `` String.raw`$\frac{1}{2}$` `` retains text without escaping.

Can I pass my `textVar` to `String.raw` in any way?

This doesn't work though `` String.raw`${textVar}` ``

Comment: No, template string syntax allows passing the raw string to tag functions, which String.raw makes use of.  Once the string is assigned it is too late.  The best you will be able to do is keep a list of latex commands and "fix" them at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that your mentioned string literal is already assigned to `textVar` and you want to get the raw string that you entered in the string literal afterwards, then no, that is not possible.

Once the string literal is assigned to the variable, that information is lost.

If you cannot escape the backslashes in your string literal, the only option is to assign the `String.raw` directly to your `textVar`.

```js
let textVar = String.raw`$\frac{1}{2}$`
console.log(textVar);
```

Comment: If textVar is a field in post api body, how do I apply String.raw on it ?

Comment: Do you mean that you get this string from an AJAX request? If that's the case then non of this applies. You get the response already as a string instead of a string literal.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting a string from AJAX, but when i try to use this string for someother purpose in backend, I'm losing these escape characters

Comment: Then the JSON was not formed correctly and you should probably talk to the backend developers.  If they used a standard JSON library to serialize, backslashes should have been escaped when serialized.  Double check and look at the actual JSON response you get from the backend API and see if it is correct.

Comment: I get this in request body, and I'm the one trying to use this string in backend to generate slug out of it @user120242

Comment: @shaara Do you mean that your backend is JavaScript? Or are you trying to insert this string directly into your JavaScript from the backend?

Comment: backend is Javascript (nodejs) @Ivar

Comment: @shaara So to be clear, in your backend you make an AJAX request to a different API which returns some strings in LaTeX format. And when you try to use the response, the escape characters are missing? That means that either the JSON was invalid to begin with in which case, that should be fixed by the maintainers of the API, or you are parsing values twice, but you haven't shown how you use any of this, so that is impossible to tell from my end. Either way this is not possible to fix using `String.raw`.

Comment: Sorry @Ivar my bad, I have not been clear in my above comments

I have an api in my backend which a client calls and sends this Latex format text in their request body, so, I get this in req.body which I'm trying to handle and losing these escape characters

Comment: @shaara Is this request body in JSON format? If this is the case then it should be fixed on the side that makes this request. If the client sends valid JSON and you parse it correctly, then those escape characters should not be a problem.

Comment: after parsing the json request into req.body using bodyparser, this is how my req.body look like

`{ question: '$\frac{1}{3}$ of $\frac{3}{4}$ of a Number is $\textbf{2}$ $\frac{1}{2}$ of $10$. what is the number?'}

let textVar = req.body.question escaping characters

let inputObj = {question: req.body.question}`
 
this obj retains the characters which I'm using to insert into db

Comment: @shaara Yes that is invalid JSON. It should look like this: `{"question":"$\\frac{1}{3}$ of $\\frac{3}{4}$ of a Number is $\\textbf{2}$ $\\frac{1}{2}$ of $10$. what is the number?"}`

Comment: @Ivar, got it, Its impossible without double `\\\` to avoid escaping then ?

Comment: Correct. Theoretically you could write your own JSON parser that would work in this case, but that would cost you a lot of time, plus that one would probably break when valid JSON is entered (for example when you pass `\"` which would add a double quote to the string instead of ending the JSON value). Getting the front end to send valid JSON would definitely be more practical.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ivar, but how is it not lost if I assign it to a dict/object

`let inputObj = {question: req.body.question}
console.log(inputObj)` gives out
`{ question: '$\frac{1}{3}$ of $frac{3}{4}$ ...'}`

Comment: It isn't lost.  You are copy/pasting decorated visual representations of the data that does not represent valid JavaScript (nor JSON) representations of the actual string.  It is visualized that way only for convenience of the eye.  JSON exists for a reason: proper serialization of data.  Whatever it is you are doing to serialize the JavaScript data to a string is wrong.  The output you should be using is from `JSON.stringify(data)`, not some copy/paste of the data you get from the console.

Comment: @Shaara What did you end up doing for this?